# Converting huggingface model to safetensors failing with larger model

Tags: huggingface

I use this code to merge a fine-tuned model on a machine with a A100-40GB:

```
from peft import AutoPeftModelForCausalLM
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
import torch

checkpoint_dir = "/data/Llama-2-13b-chat-hf-v1/checkpoint-780"
merge_dir = "merged_llama-2-13b-chat-hf-v1"

# Load adapter model
model = AutoPeftModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(checkpoint_dir, use_cache=False, torch_dtype=torch.float16, device_map='auto', offload_folder="offload", offload_state_dict = True)

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint_dir)
merged_model = model.merge_and_unload()

# Save the merged model
merged_model.save_pretrained(merge_dir,safe_serialization=True)
tokenizer.save_pretrained(merge_dir)
print("Pretraining Done. Merged model saved in:", merge_dir)
```

But when I use the 13b instead of the 7b llama-2 model I am getting the following error:

> NotImplementedError: Cannot copy out of meta tensor; no data!

I can set safe_serialization=False for it to work and merge, but then its not in safetensor format. I think its a offloading issue but is there any way to get around this?